# Are hypersurfaces robustly simply connected?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

(This is a followup to [my previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/217598/are-rationally-connected-varieties-robustly-simply-connected) on rationally connected varieties)

Let $X$ be a smooth hypersurface of degree $d$ in $\mathbb P^n$, $n \geq 3$.

Let $f: Y \to X$ be a finite morphism from a normal variety $Y$ to $X$, generically of degree $k$. Let $D$ be the branch divisor of $f$.

> Do we have for some constant $c_{d,n}$ the inequality
>   $$ H^{n-2} \cdot D \geq (c_{d,n}-o(1)) k?$$

As $n \geq 3$, by Lefschetz $X$ is simply connected, so clearly $D$ is nonzero and hence $H^{n-1} \cdot D \geq 1$. I'm asking if the inequality can be strengthened.

Jason Starr's [positive answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/217652/18060) to my previous question, plus the fact that Fano varieties are rationally connected, shows the answer is yes when $d < n+1$.

But I don't know anything about the Calabi-Yau case $d=n+1$ or the general type case, except that by pulling back covers from projective space you can see that $c_{d,n} \leq 2 d$ if it exists.

If the answer is yes, the only strategy I can see to prove it would be some Lefschetz type argument where you show that a cover extends. But it's certainly not the case that a ramified cover of a hypersurface in projective space always is a pullback of a ramified cover of projective space - then the branch divisor would always be a multiple of the hyperplane class.

Comment: How about the following?  Fix, once and for all, a linear projection $g:X\to \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ that is finite and flat.  Denote the branch divisor of $g$ by $E_0$.  The branch divisor of $g\circ f$ should be $E_0+g_*D$ (where $g_*$ is defined using norms as in Mumford's "Lectures on curves on an algebraic surface").  Now use the result for $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$.

Comment: There is a mistake in my previous comment. Denoting by $D_f$ the branch divisor of $f$, the branch divisor of $g\circ f$ should be $g_*D_f + \text{deg}(f)\cdot E_0$.  The formula has to be linear for precomposing $f$ with a finite 'etale morphism.

Comment: The degree of $E_0$ is $d(d-1)$.  Your lower bound on the degree of a branch divisor in $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ is $$H^{n-2}\cdot(g_*D_f + \text{deg}(f)E_0) \geq 2\text{deg}(g\circ f).$$  Simplifying yields, $$H^{n-2}\cdot D_f \geq (2d -d(d-1))\text{deg}(f).$$ Unfortunately this is useless for $d \geq 2$.

Comment: @JasonStarr Any argument really has to use $n \geq 3$ because it's dramatically false for $n =2$.

Comment: Yes, also the technique I was proposing would apply to any projective variety, not just hypersurfaces.  So that is another reason it cannot work.

Comment: Just a remark--if $n\geq 4$ the branch divisor is in fact always a multiple of the hyperplane class.  In fact it seems likely to me that in this case the cover does extend, at least if you require $f: Y\to X$ to be flat (which would follow if you require that $Y$ be Cohen-Macaulay rather than just normal).

Comment: @DanielLitt Oh good point! Why do you think it might extend in the Cohen-Macauley case? I'm fine with adding that additional assumption if it leads to an interesting result.

Comment: Well I claim it's enough to extend to a formal neighborhood by some results in my thesis (some algebraization argument).  This is a purely deformation-theoretic question, which involves some Ext between N_X/P^n and \Omega^1_Y/X.  My instinct is that the relevant group is zero but haven't checked yet.

Comment: You need Cohen-Macaulay so that f_*O_Y is locally free over O_X, to apply the algebraization stuff.

Comment: The algebraization stuff (e.g., SGA2) works for finite etale covers because finite etale covers are rigid, even on open affines.  Thus, you can glue extensions from open affines, and thus extend finite etale covers to the formal neighborhood of your ample divisor in the ambient variety.  But branched covers are not rigid, especially not on open affines.  How are you going to extend to the first infinitesimal neighborhood of the hypersurface in projective space?  I am not saying it cannot be done, but I think it requires more than SGA2.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't mention the following, but others in the past have (wrongly) assumed that branched covers deform to infinitesimal neighborhoods, cf. Prop. 5.1, v1 of "Counterexample to the Hodge Conjecture".

Comment: @JasonStarr: Etaleness is irrelevant for the algebraization business (that is, extending from a formal neighborhood of $X$ to the ambient space).  This follows from e.g. SGA 2, Expose XII or some stuff in my thesis.  The hard part is indeed getting to the infinitesimal neighborhoods; if $Y$ is smooth, this boils down to the vanishing of (I think) $\text{Ext}^2_Y(\Omega^1_{Y/X}, f^*I_{X/P^n}^k/I_{X/P^n]^{k+1})$ (hopefully I got that right--I haven't had a chance to check yet).  I would expect this to vanish, at least if $n > 4$.

Comment: Here is a case to consider: let $X$ be a hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n$ of degree $d\geq n$ (so when $d$ equals $n$, this is Fano).  Let $Y\to X$ be the branched cover of degree $(n-1)!$ parameterizing pointed lines $(L,p)$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ such that $L\cap X$ has multiplicity $\geq n$ at $p$ as a divisor.  This scheme admits an evident closed immersion to the projectivized tangent bundle of $X$, and the pullback of the relative $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is an invertible sheaf on $Y$.  If $Y$ extends to $\widehat{Y}$, then SGA2 implies that $\mathcal{O}(1)$ extends to $\widehat{Y}$ ($n\geq 4$) . . .

Comment: . . . Now the pushforward to $X$ of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is locally free and contains $\Omega_X$ as a locally direct summand.  I don't see any reason why this locally free sheaf should extend to the formal neighborhood $\widehat{X}$, much less why it should extend as an algebra.

Comment: One more comment about the branched cover $Y\to X$ in my previous comment: you can take a pencil $X_t$ extending $X$ and then form $Y_t$.  However, for the Stein factorization $\widetilde{Y}$ of the total space, (a) $\widetilde{Y}$ is not flat over $\mathbb{P}^n$, and (b) the induced morphism $\widetilde{Y}\times_{\mathbb{P}^n} X \to Y$ fails to be an isomorphism in codimension $1$.  So the intersection with $X$ of the branch divisor of $\widetilde{Y}$ differs from the branch divisor of $Y$, which is useless for Sawin's quextion.

Comment: @JasonStarr: Well, I have to admit I don't know if the relevant Ext group vanishes--and your example does indeed seem unlikely to extend.  This is some explicit vanishing question though--I'll think about it some more and comment again if I can prove vanishing in some large class of cases.